Java type in JDBS PreparedStatements for Postgresql ltree[] (Array of ltree elements)
I have a JDBC Prepared Statement that take a parameter of ltree[], the hierarchical tree-like data type in Postgres.
My goal is to query multiple entries from my_table, where the path is ltree type and is the primary key. Performance is critical. So I'm using Prepared Statements. I don't want to construct the query programmatically, so I want to pass the list of primary keys (ltree[]) as a parameter.
Here is my prepared Statement:
PreparedStatement myStatement =  connection.prepareStatement(
                """
                        SELECT path
                        FROM   my_table
                        WHERE  path IN ( ? )
                        """);

The code where I try to populate the parameter:
ArrayList<String> listWithQuotes = new ArrayList<>();
listWithQuotes.add("A.B.C");
listWithQuotes.add("A.B");

Array array = connection.createArrayOf("ltree[]",listWithQuotes.toArray() );
            currStatement.setArray(1,array);
            ResultSet rs = currStatement.executeQuery();

Here is the error message I'm getting:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unable to find server array type for provided name ltree[].


Fix your indenting so we can read your code.

Is the [] supposed to be in the name? What happens if you try just "ltree"?

The error is in this line.
connection.createArrayOf("ltree[]",listWithQuotes.toArray());

The first parameter this function is expecting is the type of the elements that will be stored in the array, and the one you are using is ltree (without the []).
I also noticed another error in your query.
SELECT path FROM my_table WHERE path IN ( ? )
The IN operator doesn't work with ltree type. You can look at the specific operators in the documentation that you shared and I believe the one that you need is <@. So the query will be like this:
SELECT path FROM my_table WHERE path <@ ( ? )

SELECT path FROM my_table WHERE path IN ( 'A.B.C','A.B.C.D' ) is perfectly working, I'm just trying to use the same query with JDBC Prepared Statements.

changing ltree[] to ltree results following error
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: ltree = ltree[]"
